# How do I apply the jQuery unobtrusive validation to a DropDownList editor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Too many people have told me to apply the `required` class to make the field required. I don't want the good ol' `required` attribute; I want the new attribute sets for validation. This is what I've tried without success:

This is my editor template:

```
@using Comair.RI.UI.Core
@{
    var list = this.GetModelSelectList();
    var listWithSelected = new SelectList(list.Items, list.DataValueField, list.DataTextField, Model);
}
@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired)
{
    //var att = "data-val-required=\"string.Format("The {0} field is required", ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName)
    var att = string.Format("The {0} field is required.", ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName);
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model, listWithSelected, " - select - ", 
    new Dictionary<string, object> {{"data-val-number=", "The field " + ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName + " must be a number."}, {"data-val", true}, {"data-val-required", att}})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply decorate the corresponding view model property with the desired validation attributes. For example:

```
public class Core
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@using Comair.RI.UI.Core
@{
    var list = this.GetModelSelectList();
    var listWithSelected = new SelectList(list.Items, list.DataValueField, list.DataTextField, Model);
}
@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, listWithSelected, " - select - ")
}
```

Also notice that the first argument you are passing to the `DropDownListFor` helper must represent a lambda expression pointing to a simple scalar property type (such as integer or string). That's why in my example I have illustrated how to apply the Required attribute to the corresponding Id property on your view model and then simply bind the DropDownList to it. Then the helper will take care to generate all the necessary attributes for unobtrusive validation to work. In your example you were binding the dropdownlist to the model with `m => Model` which first is an incorrect lambda expression because you are capturing the `Model` value from the outside and even worse it is a complex type which is not very compatible with the helper.

There's just one thing you should be aware of. If this template is not called within a form (`Html.BeginForm` or `Ajax.BeginForm`) the helper will not emit client side validation attributes such as `data-required` and so on. You could workaround this issue by instantiating the FormContext if not present:

```
@if (ViewContext.FormContext == null)
{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, listWithSelected, " - select - ")
```

This will ensure that the helper will always emit the validation attributes.